# How to identify RocksDb and Segments

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

in the following article it is told that Kafka Streams if they are using windowing, 'rocksdb' will create a Segment for the windows retention.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Streams+Internal+Data+Management

```
The second difference is about RocksDB instances: instead of using a 
single instance, Streams uses multiple instances (called “segments”) 
for different time periods. After the window retention time has passed 
old segments can be dropped
```

Is this still the case, in our application I try to identify this segments to create some automation to delete these files but while our application is running like 3 weeks and window retention is one day, I can't find 21 such segment files...

Is this article still accurate?

Thx for answers...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it still accurate. However, you should **not manually delete** those files. Kafka Streams manages the state and you might end with corrupted state if you do.

Why do you expect 21 segments?

(Also, newer release handle segments slightly differently. Cf. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-319%3A+Replace+segments+with+segmentInterval+in+WindowBytesStoreSupplier)

Comment: I assumed from the wording that segments will be additional files. Ok here is our dilemma, we have in our topics 7 days retention, so there it no unlimited grow in our topic sizes but if I understand correctly there is no such mechanism for Rocksdb, our topic will not contain any message older then 7 days but Rocksdb - Stores can contain 21 days old objects or more, so it will grow and grow. It seems only logical way to maintain this, is to delete state store periodically and let the Kafka Stream to create the store again at the start or is there a better way to manage rocksdb size?

Comment: A segment is a whole RocksDB instance and each segment it is mapped to its own directory. If a segment expires, Kafka Streams delete the whole directory. Note, that you need to use a `WindowedStore` for this -- if you use a `KeyValueStore` there is no expiration happening.